# デプロイ環境でのDBエラーを解決するために、マイグレーションファイルを適切に削除したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

デプロイ環境でrails db:migrateすると下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
Unknown table 'アプリ名_production.restaurants': DROP TABLE `restaurants`
```

localでrails db:migrate:statusを実行してDBの変更履歴を見ると以下のようになっています。

```
   up     20200116052507  Create posts
   up     20200116052828  Create places
   up     20200116111220  Add image to places
   up     20200117061424  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20200118113702  Devise create users
   up     20200118120853  Add nickname to users
   up     20200119075846  Add details to posts
   up     20200119080633  Add user id to posts
   up     20200121082518  Add column to users
   up     20200219114334  Remove tel from places
   up     20200219114621  Add prefecture to places
   up     20200219114902  Add description to places
   up     20200219115902  Drop table restaurants
   up     20200220103437  Create subplaces
   up     20200223114625  Remove restaurant from posts
```

開発段階でrestaurantsテーブルというのを削除する際

```rb
  def change
    drop_table :[削除したいテーブル名]
  end
```

というマイグレーションファイルをmigrateしたのと、ターミナルでrails destroy model restaurant　でモデルを削除しました。おそらくこの工程が影響して上記上から４つ目の
up 20200117061424 ********** NO FILE **********　と
下から３つ目の
up 20200219115902 Drop table restaurants　が作成され、それらが作用してエラーが出ていると思われます。
dropする際のマイグレーションのコードも良くない書き方をしていたようで、ロールバックもできず困っています。
やはりロールバックできない状態だと、マイグレーションファイルの削除も変更もできないでしょうか？
上記２つのマイグレーションファイルを削除することができればエラーは解決すると思われるのですが、何かいい方法はあるでしょうか？
ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 念のため、まずはローカル環境でDBのバックアップとリストアを練習しておくといいです。
2. ローカルの実験環境のDBのバックアップし、念のため別マシンや外部HDDなどにコピーを取っておきます。
3. マイグレート状態は「schema_migrations」に格納されているので、この場合「20200117061424」と「20200219115902」のレコードを実験環境で削除してください。
4. 「rails db:migrate:status」を実行すると、「20200117061424」はなくなり、「20200219115902」はdownになるはずです。そうなったら「db/migrate/20200219115902_drop_table_restaurants.rb」（ファイル名は違うかもしれませんので、先頭の「20200219115902」を確認してください）を削除または「.old」などを付加して実行されないようにします。
5. 再度「rails db:migrate:status」を実行すると、先ほどの2つはなくなって、全てupになるはずです。
6. 「rails db:migrate」で何も起こらなければ、整合性は取れているはずです。
7. デプロイ環境のDBのバックアップを取って、同様に外部にもコピーをしておきます。
8. 3.4.5.をデプロイ環境で実行すれば、DBがローカルのマイグレーション途中と同じ構成になるはずですので、6.でマイグレーションできるようになるはずです。
9. うまくいったら、他もテストして、問題ないか確認してください。
10. 問題があったら、一旦バックアップから戻して、再度最初から手順を確認してみてください。

    こんな感じでできるはずですので、試してみてください。なお、デプロイ環境のDBのバックアップとリストアに自信がなければ、出来そうな人に手伝ってもらうようにして、デプロイ環境を破壊しないように注意した方が良いでしょう。